# how can i use split() with a big number of elements, java

Tags: java

I need to process a big text file, there are almost 400 column in each line, and almost 800000 lines in the file, the format of each line in the file is like:

340,9,2,3........5,2,LA

what I want to do is, for each line, if the last column is LA, then print the first column of this line.

i write a simple program to do it

```
    BufferedReader bufr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("A.txt"));
    BufferedWriter bufw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter ("LA.txt"));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = bufr.readLine()) != null) {
        String [] text = new String [388];
        text = line.split(",");
        if (text [387] == args[2]) {

            bufw.write(text[0]);
            bufw.newLine();
            bufw.flush();
        }

    }

    bufw.close();
    bufr.close();
```

but it seems the length of an array cant be that big, i received a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
since i'm using split(",") in order to get the last column of a line, and it will be out of array bounds, how can I do with it? thanks.

Comment: It should be like this ---> String [] text = line.split(",");

Comment: There is no guarantee that the array will be 388-long on the split as well. An empty line, for example, would split to an array[1].

Comment: i changed it like what you said, but it still out of bounds, since i have almost 400 columns, is it has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text` does not need to be initialized, `String.split` will create a correctly sized array:

```
String[] text = line.split(",");
```

You're also comparing Strings using reference equality (`==`). You should be using `.equals()`:

```
if (text[387].equals(args[2])) { ... }
```

You're probably getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the the index `387` is too big. If you want to get last element, use this:

```
text[text.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify and try this

```
String [] text = line.split(",");
    if (text [text.length - 1].equals(args[2])) {

        bufw.write(text[0]);
        bufw.newLine();
        bufw.flush();
    }
```

Assuming `args[2]` is `LA`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] text;
```

Change your code to this.  You don't need to initialize a size.  When the String.split method executes it will automatically initialize the correct size for your array.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the first and the last column, then there is no need to create an array out of the current line.

You could do something like this:

```
final String test = "340,9,2,354,63,5,5,45,634,5,5,2,LA";
final char delimiter = ',';

final String lastColumn = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(delimiter) + 1);
if (lastColumn.equals("LA")) {
  final String firstColumn = test.substring(0, test.indexOf(delimiter));
  System.out.println(firstColumn);
}
```

This code extracts the last column first and tests it. If it matches "LA", then it extract the first column. It will ignore the remaining content of the line.

Your code would be:

```
BufferedReader bufr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("A.txt"));
BufferedWriter bufw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter ("LA.txt"));

String line = null;
while ((line = bufr.readLine()) != null) {
    final String lastColumn = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(delimiter) + 1);
    if (lastColumn.equals(args[2])) {
        bufw.write(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(delimiter)));
        bufw.newLine();
        bufw.flush();
    }
}
bufw.close();
bufr.close();
```

(this code is not tested yet, but you get the idea :))